# How is this date comparison not equal?

Tags: php, string, date, equals

```
$days = $days_of_week[2];

if (date('d/m/Y') == $days) {
    $today = "Correct";
} else if (date('d/m/Y') != $days) {
    $today = '<br>Non correct<br>';
    $today1 = date('d/m/Y');
    $today2 = $days_of_week[2];
}
```

This returns when I echo the `$today`, `$today1` and `$today2`.

> Non correct 06/11/2013 06/11/2013

Am I missing something here? Tried `===`

Comment: What does `var_dump($days_of_week[2]);` output?

Comment: What is the value of `$days_of_week[2]`?

Comment: @AmalMurali It outputs, string(11) "06/11/2013 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change first string to

```
$days = trim($days_of_week[2]);
```

May be in your input is any "invisible" symbols. For example any white spaces

Comment: Works! It was indeed a white space. I notice that when I did a var_dump, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$days = $days_of_week[2];

if (date('d/m/Y') == date('d/m/Y', strtotime($days))) {
  $today = "Correct";
} else if (date('d/m/Y') != date('d/m/Y', strtotime($days))) {
  $today = '<br>Non correct<br>';
  $today1 = date('d/m/Y');
  $today2 = $days_of_week[2];
}
```

Comment: Unexpected { in if (date('d/m/Y') == date('d/m/Y', strtotime($days)) {

Comment: Thanks but it was a white space, got it fixed by trim.